# Query kafka for a message(s) by key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a simple kafka configuration:

- default console-producer writes to one topic with one partition
- custom processor (which implements `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor`) reads from kafka and process messages.

During processing I validate a batch of messages, if validation fails I write to log the key of the first message of a failed batch.
Is it possible in kafka to query for a message with given key/offset? Or get 100 messages after that message?

Comment: Yes and no, Consider Consumer#seek() and Kafka Streams "Interactive Queries". Also check out this questions (your question a a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=query+kafka